# Java Kerberos login - store credentials

Tags: java, kerberos, credentials

I have configured Kerberos for various authentication purposes. OS command line tools are working and return renewable tickets with a configurable lifetime.

I now need to obtain tickets in a custom application and store them away in a ticket cache file that I can use with any Kerberos system tool. Since the custom application is Java-based, it seems most natural to use Java means to authenticate and deal with the tickets.

I have been following the example given in [JAAS Authentication Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jaas/tutorials/GeneralAcnOnly.html) and successfully authenticated to my Kerberos KDC. Now, I would like to

1. Fine tune the properties of the obtained TGT ticket. What I get is a non-renewable ticket with unlimited lifetime. Instead, I would like to request a renewable ticket with configurable lifetime, renewable lifetime etc.
2. Store the obtained ticket into a ticket cache file for use outside the sample application (e.g. command line kerberos utilities).

I do have two open questions:

1. How can I configure the login context to obtain tickets with the desired settings?
2. How can I extract the credentials from the authenticated subject and save them into a ticket cache file?

Update: Digging into the code, it seems that `sun.security.krb5.KrbAsReqBuilder` is used to do the Kerberos communication. The lifetime options seem to be hardcoded in there, although `sun.security.krb5.KrbAsReq` allows to specify them. Seems I might need to take another route to get what I want.

Update2: After reviewing other options, I have decided to use a modified version of the original C source code for MIT Kerberos' kinit tool instead of using Java at all.

Comment: How do you obtain a TGT? By OS-means or through Java? Anyway, you have to tweak your `krb5.conf`.

Comment: I want to obtain the TGT through Java, as in the tutorial. My krb5.conf is set up such that OS command line tools (either Heimdal or MIT) return tickets with the desired properties. Java apparently uses its own mechanisms to get the tickets and does not obey krb5.conf settings.

Comment: If you plan to do that you need to use a password callback handler for the LoginContext.  Java does obey `krb5.conf` but not to that extent like MIT/Heimdal does. Unfortunately, I wasn't to file a man page for that :(

Comment: As far as I understand the documentation, a password callback handler is responsible for retrieving a user password or equivalent. The documentation does not seem to indicate how a password callback could change the behaviour of the LoginModule which uses this password for authentication.

Comment: The callbacks provide username and password only. Behavior is changed by krb5.conf only.

Comment: Do **not** use that Sun classes. They are private.

Comment: Do you have any alternative class suggestions for the purpose of a simple Kerberos ticket utility? I do not want any overhead of a huge framework that does Kerberos but also lots of other stuff which I don't need and which may cause compatibility issues with my Java execution environment.

Comment: What about the options in the `krb5.conf`? Don't they suffice? Alternatively, I would extend Sun's login module and would proceed as-is.

Comment: `krb5.conf` is set up correctly for system command line client utilities. Apparently, Java is not using anything from that file besides realm and KDC settings. I'm afraid extending Sun's login module won't help either. This module uses exactly the classes mentioned above, which do not seem to allow to specify details about the requested tickets.

Comment: Did you check the code which reads that file?

Comment: The problem is that all the stuff you want to do is out of scope of the GSS-API this is purely a Kerberos issue. Most people resort to the base Kerberos 5 API in MIT or in Heimdal but since this is a "private" API do not expect code to be portable. Same does apply to Java. If you start using Sun's classes which seems to suit your case, it might break with new updates or won't work at all with other JVM implementations.

The best might be a C shim for the MIT Kerberos 5 API, interact with that, build credential cache and use Java as usual.